# ThreeJS Change parent position based on child object’s geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3D object and a cube mesh, added mesh as a child to 3D object. Now I want to change position of 3D object inside mesh so that I can control pivot points of the cube mesh. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abnormalcoder/pen/bGGzWVW)

```
            mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
            mesh.name = "mesh1";
            mesh.position.set(0.2, 0, 0);
            scene.add(mesh);
            var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
            scene.add(mesh1);
            mesh1.name = "mesh2";

            mesh1.position.set(0.4, 0, 0);
            mesh.add(mesh1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add mesh1 to mesh (mesh.add(mesh1)), not to the scene. Then simply change mesh1.position as needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the line scene.add(mesh1) because you want to add your cube to the parent object and not to the scene.
if you want to change the position of your object3D you just have to access the position attribute or translate geometry of cube